# How to set the selected value in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have some options

```
<%=select_tag "language", "<option>Malayalam</option><option>Tamil</option>
<option>Hindi</option><option>Kannada</option>".html_safe %>
```

so after submission, when i reload the page i got the selected value in JSON **@one_data["language"]**. I need to set this value as selected value in **select_tag**

i have tried some way like

```
 <%=select_tag "language", "<option>Malayalam</option><option>Tamil</option>
 <option>Hindi</option><option>Kannada</option>".html_safe,  :selected =>
 @one_data["language"] %>
```

Comment: answered a billion times on the SO and the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `options_for_select`:

```
<%= select_tag "language", options_for_select(['Malayalam', 'Tamil', 'Hindi', 'Kannada'], @one_data['language']) %>
```